# What's the most time and idiot-proof way to store metadata?

Tags: metadata

For example, let's say I keep a bunch of documents, images, videos, and ZIP archives on a remote computer/storage facility (say S3), which I download in a way that strips the files of their creation dates, et al. (say FTP) after a number of years (say in 2050).

What would be the best way to store file metadata to survive such a horrifying process?

Comment: You mean, "which I **upload** in a way..."?

Comment: Start -> Run -> `cmd`.  Open your directory, enter `dir /T:C`.  Right click, "Select All".  Open Notepad, paste.  Voila!  Amazing, I know.  If you're on Linux, use `ls` with the appropriate switches (`man ls` should have more then enough information).

Comment: @Breakthrough: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Breakthrough Well creation dates and FTP are just an example. I would have titles, comments and ratings too. Tons. I have almost every file I ever created in my whole life.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dir` command under Windows, or the `ls` command under Linux to obtain a directory listing in a command console, with the file creation dates.

If you are running Windows, go to Start -> Run -> `cmd`  (or, hit WinKey+R).  Move to the directory where your files are, and enter `dir /T:C` to 
obtain a directory listing with the *file creation date*.  Right click, select all, and paste into notepad.  Just save the directory listing output with your files.

If you're running Linux, 
you can get a similar output using `ls -lc` (the `c` flag uses the inode creation date instead of last modified date).